# Kafka producer to read from a local Linux folder

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, real-time, kafka-producer-api

I am writing a Kafka producer
It has to read data from a local Linux folder and write to my topic
Is it possible to do something like that?

What would be my code snippet here (in Scala)

Business case -

Real time data will be written on a local Linux folder in form of CSV files here - /data/data01/pharma/2017/

How can I move this data to a topic I created?

My consumer will read this data and add to Spark streaming data frame for processing

Comment: Spark Streaming can watch local file directories. Whatever you want to do with it is up to the limits of the Spark API... So yes, there's a Kafka producer api

Comment: ok . thanks for your comment/reply.  but my requirement here is - real time processing .. so data will be written on local linux folder. so kafka producer will read the same, and kafka consumer, ( using spark will process the same ) I cannot have spark in producer ( can i ) ; any suggestions on how to meet this requirement ( or am i missing something very basic ) .. I am newbie here.

Comment: Spark can definitely be a producer and consumer...

Answer (score 2):

> Real time data will be written on a local linux folder

There's many frameworks that allow you to handle this

Those I'm aware of with Kafka connections

- [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/kafka-output.html)
- FluentD / [Fluentbit](https://fluentbit.io/)
- [Spark Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-sources) (or SparkSQL / Structured Streaming)
- [Flume](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#kafka-sink)
- [Apache Nifi](http://ingest.tips/2015/01/16/integrating-apache-nifi-apache-kafka/) (better to run as a cluster, though, not locally)
- [Kafka Connect](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) with a FileStreamConnector which is included with Apache Kafka (don't need Confluent Platform)

Point being, don't reinvent the wheel which bears the risk of writing unnecessary (and possibly faulty) code, although, you could easily write your own KafkaProducer code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a single file, then

```
cat ${file} | bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my_topic
```

If the files are created dynamically, then you need to monitor them and feed it to kafka-console-producer.sh

[Kafka producer to read data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377852/kafka-producer-to-read-data-files?rq=1)

Comment: one more help sir, now, i am trying to customize the producer to use spark streaming to read from the kafka topic. any idea how to do that .

Comment: Use structured streaming, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html